# Special symbols in subject of emails

Tags: jakarta-mail, html-email

We are currently working on a defect to allow special symbols also to be seen in email subject. The email is text/html mime type.

Currently, if the subject should have a heart symbol it is shown as "&heart" but in the email body a "heart" symbol is shown.

Can someone help us with the solution to have special symbols also part of subject?

Here is the code snippet.

```
public boolean send(String to, String from, String subject, String templatePath, Map map) {
// create a mime message using the mail sender implementation
MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

// create the message using the specified template
MimeMessageHelper helper;
try
{

  helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
  helper.setTo(to);
  helper.setSubject(subject);
  helper.setFrom(from);

  String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(engine, templatePath, map);
  helper.setText(text, true);
  send(mimeMessage);
  log.debug("in send  at start" + this.getClass().getName()
            + ":SUCCESS: Sendig mail to" + to + " from " + from + " subject "
            + subject);
} catch (MessagingException e)
{
  throw new MailPreparationException("unable to create the mime message helper", e);
} catch (Exception e)
{
  log.debug("in send  at start" + this.getClass().getName() + ":Failed sending mail"
            + to + " from " + from + " subject " + subject);
  // throw new
  // MailPreparationException("unable to create the mime message helper",
  // e);
}
return false;
```

}
  public boolean send(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {

```
try
{

  Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
  BodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
  multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
  bodyPart.setContent(mimeMessage.getContent(), "text/html");
  mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);
  mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
} catch (Exception e)
{
  log.error("in send  at start" + this.getClass().getName() + ":Failed sending mail"
            + e.getMessage());

  // e.printStackTrace();
  throw e;
  // return false;
}
return true;
```

}

Comment: Please accept some answers to previous questions that you have asked - you will find people are more willing to help you, and it makes StackOverflow a better place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public static String HTMLDecode(String encodedHTML) {

        return encodedHTML.replaceAll("&iexcl;", "\u00A1")
                          .replaceAll("&cent;", "\u00A2")
                          .replaceAll("&pound;", "\u00A3")
                          .replaceAll("&curren;", "\u00A4")
                          .replaceAll("&yen;", "\u00A5")
                          .replaceAll("&brvbar;", "\u00A6")
                          .replaceAll("&sect;", "\u00A7")
                          .replaceAll("&uml;", "\u00A8")
                           ........
```

Comment: Let me know if someone wants the entire code for this method...cheers

Comment: I have the same problem. Usual symbols like "\u0044" converts to "D", but special symbols like "\u00A1" converts to "?" in email subject...

Answer (score 1):

You can send as Unicode / UTF-8.

Comment: we fixed this by writing a method that converts encode htmll to utf-8